# Multithreading in C/C++ without waiting for the thread to finish

Tags: c, multithreading

All the examples that I have seen about multithreading uses this method in the `main` method to wait until the thread is done:

```
pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
```

But what if I don't want it to wait? I want my main function to continue as the thread is doing it's work, but at the same time, I don't want main to exit before the thread exists. Is this possible in C/C++?

Comment: so, before exiting from `main` you want to wait for thread to finish, by joining to it, right?

Comment: yes but I want to run code after `joining`, I don't want to wait until the thread is done. Above code locks the mian until the thread is done.

Comment: no, you want to join just before return from main, this way - code after thread start will execute in parallel with the thread

Comment: see why don't the tutorials mention this? I thought threads don't start running unless you `join`. thanks for informing me, i'll give it a try.

Comment: just read manual about [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) `function starts a new thread in the calling process`

Comment: Your requirement is contradictory.  Either the `main()` function continues as the thread is doing its work and exits,   or it waits for the thread to complete before exiting.    The two are mutually exclusive.     The nearest you can come is for the last thing that `main()` does before returning is to wait for the other threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using `pthread_join()`, then `pthread_detach()` is an option. 
From [man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html):

> int pthread_detach(pthread_t thread);
>
> The pthread_detach() function marks the thread identified by thread
>   as detached.  When a detached thread terminates, its resources are
>   automatically released back to the system without the need for
>   another thread to join with the terminated thread.
>
> it does not prevent the thread from being
>          terminated if the process terminates using exit(3) (or equivalently,
>          if the main thread returns).